# PreferenceActivity debug

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I am trying to debug PreferenceActivity. 
I start it like this: 
`final Intent intent = new Intent(context, PreferenceActivity.class);`
`startActivity(intent);`
and in `PreferenceActivity` I added breakpoints in `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add a button to the header list.
    if (hasHeaders()) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Some action");
        setListFooter(button);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. 
What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Where you add the breakpoints? and does your PreferenceActivity correctly shown?

Answer (score 1):

To start an Activity you have to make an Intent as you do and then you have to invoke startActivity(intent);

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, PreferenceActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes, it was added in the code. I forgot to add it here. I edited the question.  Problem is that PreferenceActivity is displayed but I can't to debug it. Any breakpoint doesn't work.